# Woocommerce & Paypal | Blank Page after Paypal Checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, paypal, woocommerce, checkout

Whenever I checkout using Paypal as payment gateway, I got redirected to the thank you page with extra parameters resulting to displaying a white blank page. When I delete those parameters on the URL, the thank you page is now being displayed. I tried the Return URL on my Paypal account. Still, it doesn't work. The thank you page also is being displayed when I use other payment gateways.

Can anyone please help me to redirect from Paypal to my thank you page without the extra parameters.

URL after Paypal checkout:
https://mywoocommercestore.com/checkout/order-received/3347/?key=wc_order_5b15c94f9913d&utm_nooverride=1&amt=1.00&cc=AUD&cm=%7B%22order_id%22%3A3347%2C%22order_key%22%3A%22wc_order_5b15c94f9913d%22%7D&st=Completed&tx=2KG00400K7478654M

URL should be after checkout:
https://mywoocommercestore.com/checkout/order-received/3347/?key=wc_order_5b15c94f9913d

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will work, but can you check if you have enabled PDT in your paypal account? If yes, can you try to disable PDT and see if that helps.